# Load a controller embed to a UINavigationController from AppDelegate in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I need to display from AppDelegate a table view embed to an UINavigationController.

Normally I use

```
    let viewController: UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("prova") as ViewController
    window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

but it doesn't work with embed controller, how need to be adapted this code?

[Here is a test project.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oxs253g0y1bmgvg/launchFromDelegate.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `UINavigationController` with its identifier from your storyboard. The navigation controller should be connected to its rootViewController in the storyboard and will automatically show it.

```
let navController: UINavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("provaNavController") as UINavigationController
window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

### Update

Since you are not setting an initial view controller in the storyboard, use this code:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
let navController: UINavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("provaNavController") as UINavigationController
window?.rootViewController = navController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

You also need to clear out Main.storyboard from the general project settings:
[image]

Comment: Negative, it doesn't work, in my storyboard there's no initial controller setted. I updated the question with a project test.

Comment: Yeah, I would never thought to clear the main interface from App Target, thank you!